# Need suggestion for implementing list in android. Please...

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-emulator

I have a ListView control with 20 rows and each row contains EditText. In my case, when the keyboard is opened, the first 7 rows are visible. Consider I selected any of the EditText which in any of the rows from 8 to 20, the selected row will be position just above the keyboard. `Then I tries to type on keyboard, the ListView moves to top and the row containing the EditText in which I was editing should be hidden by the keyboard`.

`Actually I want the row should be in same position just above the keyboard even while typing on keyboard`.

`Screen1 : Screen seems like this when opened`

`Screen2 : When row #9 is selected, seems fine as the selected row came just above the keyboard`

`Screen3 : While typing on keyboard, screen seems like this as the list scrolls to top`

`Screen4 : On hiding the keyboard, screen seems like this with entered text`

[image: Screen seems like this when opened]

[image: When row #9 is selected, seems fine as the selected row came just above the keyboard]

[image: While typing on keyboard, screen seems like this as the list scrolls to top]

[image: On hiding the keyboard, screen seems like this with entered text]

Please tell me the solution.. Please

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. Add this code in your `manifest.xml` particular activity.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: I have given in my manifeat.xml file still getting same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line to the activity inside your manifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
```

Comment: if i try this row position will remains even i can type the text in EditText but if i take back to hide keyboard my EditText value has loss.